# Can not return table type from a function PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have defined record type, table type and function inside package specification.

```
TYPE name_RECORD IS RECORD (
name    VARCHAR2(244),
surname VARCHAR2(244) );

TYPE name_TABLE IS TABLE OF name_RECORD;

 function f_deps
  (i_id_dept IN employees.id_department%type) 
  return name_TABLE;
```

And wrote function which returns table type inside package body.

```
function f_deps
  (i_id_dept IN employees.id_department%type) 
  return name_TABLE  is 

CURSOR c1 IS (select * from employees ); 
t_name name_TABLE;
rec_name  name_RECORD;

BEGIN
t_name := name_TABLE();
for i in c1
LOOP

   select  name, surname  BULK COLLECT INTO t_name from employees where id_department = i_id_dept ;             

END LOOP; 

return t_name;

END f_deps;
```

Function compiles normal, but when i try to execute function like this:

```
select * from table( PACKAGE_employees.f_deps ('6')) ;
```

I get this error:

```
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 29 Column: 22
```

UPDATE: I have defined types with CREATE TYPE statement in  command line, like what Bob Jarvis suggested but I still get the same error message

```
create or replace type  name_RECORD as object (
name    VARCHAR2(244),
surname VARCHAR2(244) );

create or replace type name_TABLE AS TABLE OF name_RECORD;
```

Comment: Types created in packages can't be used in SELECT statements. SELECT statements can only make use of types created using CREATE TYPE. Best of luck.

Comment: OK , thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's not so in 12C - but the types need to be defined in the package **specification** not body.  But I think only inside PL/SQL, not from the command line.

Comment: Types are defined in package specification, I have forgot to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you cannot select using the function directly in the SQL like this:

```
select * from table( PACKAGE_employees.f_deps ('6')) ;
```

But you can do this:

```
declare
  coll package_employees.name_table;
begin
  coll := package_employees.f_deps ('6');
  for r in (select * from table(coll)) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r.name);
  end loop;
end;
```

Your function code isn't right though, it should be more like this:

```
function f_deps
  (i_id_dept IN integer) 
  return name_TABLE  is 
t_name name_TABLE;
rec_name  name_RECORD;

BEGIN

   select  name_record(name, surname)
   BULK COLLECT INTO t_name
   from employees where id_department = i_id_dept ;             

return t_name;

END f_deps;
```

i.e.

- No cursor and loop needed
- You need to construct a value of type `name_record` to bulk collect into a collection of `name_record`.

Comment: OK , thanks for the answer.  But there is any way to  see table type from function in a query result like a normal table from database ?

Comment: Yes - but your function code is wrong.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I made the changes to the code, but when I compile it,  I get  error message: Error(195,4): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: It is the same like yours  in the answer. I have defined types in package specification and in a command line like object types.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, I can select table type from a function like a normal table.  I had to remove definitions of  types  from a package specification.